# conemu: create new split from wsl bash

Tags: conemu

I use -new_console:s(v) to create new splits via command line( command prompt, cmd.exe), for eg 
`putty.exe -new_console:s <options>`

I recently installed WSL and made it default shell.
I am not able to split console using -new_console from WSL bash.
putty will start in gui and pop a message that -new_console is not a valid argument.

Kindly help,

Thanks,

Comment: You have to run the command via `ConEmuC.exe -c ...`

Comment: Hi @Maximus, thanks for response, kindly share an example, if possible an integration with wsl bash will be very much appreciated.

Comment: @someone "Kindly share an example" - have you tried e.g. `conemu.exe -c putty.exe -new_console:s <options>`?

Comment: @Anaksunaman, yes I have tried that, in windows comenu.exe is added to PATH and can be invoked from any path or run window, but in bash, conemu.exe gives error command not found.
I use conemu very extensively, have tried to write script to carry out certain tasks in new conemu splits via batch, bash, golang, python. batch is the only one that works so far, same command is generated via other scripts but something is still a miss.

Comment: just an upate, just got golang script working to open new conemu split panel, method I am using is to writting the batch command to a file and use os.exec to execute the file,
@Maximus really would love if conemu could be integrated in WSL